# Child Layout visibility gone on another child layout click event

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility, onclicklistener

My parent `Linearlayout1` contains two child Frame Layouts: `FrameLayout1` and `FrameLayout2`.

The `FrameLayout1` is on top of `FrameLayout2` but only covers the half of `FrameLayout2`.

I replaced `FrameLayout1` with some `fragment1` and also replaced `FrameLayout2` with some `fragment2`.

Now, when I click on `FrameLayout2`, the `FrameLayout1` should get Invisible. But this is not happening.

I tried the following to do so:

**userDetails.java**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userDetails, container, false);

topLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);

bottomLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout2);


view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   topLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

});

}
```

I also found that onClick listener of view is not getting called on its click.

UPDATE:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"              
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/FrameLayout2"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your xml? or at least part of it

Comment: If you want FrameLayout1 to go invisible when FrameLayout2 is clicked shouldn't you do setOnClickListener in bottomLayout instead of view?

Comment: @user1455909 - Both ways are not working. The click on bottomLayout is giving NullPointerException although I initialized it on OnCreateView.

Answer (score 2):

You've set OnClickListener to whole View instead of bottomLayout. and I think you can't cast FrameLayout to LinearLayout. The following code works fine here.

```
final FrameLayout topLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
final FrameLayout bottomLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout2);

bottomLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   topLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
});
```

Comment: I also found that only the top header part of bottomLayout is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add to your FrameLayout2 clickable. Try adding

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Then in your code setOnClickListener in your FrameLayout2. Btw I think you should cast your topLayout and your bottomLayout as `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Note that your framelayouts should be final in order to be accessed by the listener class.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I also found that only the top black header part of bottomLayout is clickable.

Comment: That could be because you have more views inside your linearlayout that  need to have the `android:clickable` parameter to `false`